# Could not load type "file" in Symfony3

Tags: twig, symfony, symfony-forms, vichuploaderbundle

I am building form with multiple image upload and I can't find solution for problem that is mentioned in title. To help me with that I included [VichUploaderBundle](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle)

Right now I am stuck with this error and I can't find why and where is mistake in code:

```
Could not load type "file"
500 Internal Server Error - InvalidArgumentException
```

Does someone knows where is the problem?

Here is code that I am using:

ProductType class:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Form\Type\VichFileType;
use AppBundle\Entity\Product;



class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
          ->add('title', TextType::class)
          ->add('content', TextType::class)
          ->add('price', TextType::class)
          ->add('categories')
          ->add('productCondition')
          ->add("images", CollectionType::class, array(
               'entry_type' => ProductImageType::class,
               'allow_add' => true,
               'allow_delete' => true
           )
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Product::class
        ));
    }




}
```

ProductImageType class

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;


class ProductImageType extends AbstractType
{
        /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
      $builder
         ->add('image', 'file')
     ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => ProductImage::class
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'product_image';
    }
}
```

services.yml

```
# Learn more about services, parameters and containers at
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html
parameters:
#    parameter_name: value

services:
#    service_name:
#        class: AppBundle\Directory\ClassName
#        arguments: ["@another_service_name", "plain_value", "%parameter_name%"]
    app.form.type.file:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Type\ProductImageType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

**EDIT:**

I removed 'file' from ProductImageType and error is gone but Twig fails to render a form. Also I tried to use self::class instead of 'file' and that didn't helped either.

```
//ProductImageType class
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
      $builder
         ->add('image')
     ;
    }
```

Results in Twig template:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label required">Images</label>
   <div id="product_images" data-prototype="<div class=&quot;form-group&quot;><label class=&quot;control-label required&quot;>__name__label__</label><div id=&quot;product_images___name__&quot;><div class=&quot;form-group&quot;><label class=&quot;control-label required&quot; for=&quot;product_images___name___image&quot;>Image</label><input type=&quot;text&quot; id=&quot;product_images___name___image&quot; name=&quot;product[images][__name__][image]&quot; required=&quot;required&quot; class=&quot;form-control&quot; /></div></div></div>"></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 2: added Twig form**

```
{% extends 'AppBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}

    <link href="{{ asset('/assets/vendor/components-font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/form-elements.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/forms.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="top-content">

                    <div class="inner-bg">
                            <div class="container">


                <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

                <div class="form-box">
                    <div class="form-top">
                        <div class="form-top-left">
                            <h3>Create new product condition!</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-top-right">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-bottom">

            {{ form_start(form, { 'attr': {'class': 'product-form'} })  }}
            {% spaceless %}
    {% if not form.vars.valid %}
            <div class="alert alert-error">
                {{ form_errors(form) }}

        {% for children in form.children %}
            {% if not children.vars.valid %}
                {{ form_errors(children) }}

                {# or with field label
                <ul>
                    {% for error in children.vars.errors %}
                        <li><b>{{ children.vars.label }}</b>: {{ error.message }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
                #}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
            </div>
    {% endif %}
        {% endspaceless %}
                {{ form_row(form.title) }}
                {{ form_row(form.content) }}
                {{ form_row(form.price) }}
                {{ form_row(form.categories) }}
                {{ form_row(form.productCondition) }}
                {{ form_row(form.images) }}
                        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit!</button>
                    {{ form_end(form) }}
        </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: @Veve in ProductImageType  class ?

Comment: @Veve I tried that and now my form is empty. It even won't render. I tried with self::class too but still it is not working

Comment: For Symfony 3, the field added in `ProductImageType.php`, I guess it should be of type `FileType` (which you need to import), and not of type `file`.

Comment: @DanCostinel I tried your suggestion and I am getting same results as one that I included in paragraph after Edit.

Comment: The `VichUploaderBundle` bundle is a requirement for your project? If not, I can provide you an example of a multi-upload functionality code.

Comment: @DanCostinel It is not. I use it because symfony documentation recommends it. You can share me your code and I will test it.

Answer (score 3):

As I promised, I'm providing you a little example of how you can create a multiple-upload form & how to get the data from the form and move it from the temp directory to your desired one, and save the path in the database.

1) Create the Entity class.

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="galleries")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\GalleryRepository")
 */
class Gallery
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $path;

    // getter for $id, setter & getter for $path here
}
```

2) Create the Form.

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
//...
$builder->add('path', FileType::class, [
    'data_class' => null,
    'multiple' => true,
    'label' => false
]);
```

3) The upload will be done using an upload service like [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html#creating-an-uploader-service) is stated. So set the directory you want your file to go in `config.yml` (don't set this parameter in `parameters.yml` because this file is ignored by git, if you push the project).

```
#app/config/config.yml
parameters:
    upload_dir: '%kernel.root_dir%/../web/upload'
```

4) Declare the service.

```
#app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.img_upload:
        class: AppBundle\Services\FileUpload
        arguments: ['%upload_dir%']
```

5) Create the service.

```
#AppBundle\Services\FileUpload.php

namespace AppBundle\Services;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

class FileUpload
{
    private $targetDir;

    public function __construct($targetDir)
    {
        $this->targetDir = $targetDir;
    }

    public function upload(UploadedFile $file)
    {
        $file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();

        empty($file_name) ? $file_name = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension() : $file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();

        $file->move($this->targetDir, $file_name);

        return $file_name;
    }
}
```

6) Create the whole logic in the controller.

```
#AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;
//...
use AppBundle\Entity\Gallery;
use AppBundle\Form\GalleryType;
//class...

/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $gallery = new Gallery();
    $form = $this->createForm(GalleryType::class, $gallery, [
        'action'=>$this->generateUrl('homepage'),
        'method'=>'POST'
    ]);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $paths = $form->get('path')->getData();

        foreach ($paths as $path){
            $img = $this->get('app.img_upload')->upload($path);

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection();
            $stmt = $em->prepare('INSERT INTO galleries SET path=?');
            $stmt->execute([$img]);

            // THIS IS THE PROBLEM I ENCOUNTER! I COULDN'T USE NORMAL DOCTRINE WAY TO SAVE EACH IMAGE PATH INTO THE DB. KNOW THE FIX? POST IT HERE PLEASE!
            // $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            // $em->persist($gallery);
            // $em->flush();

            //LE: I've found the "bug": you need to instantiate, for each $path, a new $gallery object, then set the data for it, + persist & flush.
        }

        $this->addFlash('success', 'The image(s) were successfully uploaded');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('homepage');
    }

    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', ['form'=>$form->createView()]);
}
```

7) Finally, display the form.

```
# app/Resource/views/default/index.html.twig
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.path) }}
    <button type="submit" title="Upload an image">
        Upload
    </button>
{{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you should add it to your form:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
     $builder->add('image', FileType::class);
}
```

In Symfony 3 a form type is always passed by its fully qualified class name

Comment: I tried that but I have a wired problem in Twig template. You can check result from twig under Edit paragraph

Comment: Wich template is that ?

Comment: it is bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig form template

Comment: file type is supposed to render an input with type file in a div that's all.where does that piece of html come from ?

Comment: I edited my post with twig file. I am not sure why I am getting this html code. Does it have some connection with Vich bundle