# Symfony2.8 form FileType multiple true

Tags: php, symfony

I use Symfony 2.8 and want created multiple form for upload file, add `"multiple" => true` but in action have only one file (

my form

```
        $builder
        ->add('files', 'file', array(
            'label' => 'File',
            "attr" => array(
                "accept" => "image/*, application/pdf",
                "multiple" => true,
            )


        ))
        ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Send'));

public function addFileAction(Request $request, OutboundInvoice $outboundInvoice)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new FileType());

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $data = $form->getData();
```

in data have

```
$data = {array} [1]
 files = {Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile} [7]
```

but select 2 files

how to select two file and get in action this UploadedFile ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Symfony 2.8 I guess you need to do like this (and for more info see the official documentation):

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType;
//...
$builder
->add('files', FileType::class, [
    //...
    'multiple' => true,
])
```

For getting the uploaded files in the controller, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41900411/4548751) answer.

Comment: I do  - `FileType::class` = `file` and add `            "attr" => array(
                "accept" => "image/*, application/pdf",
                "multiple" => true,
            )`

select two file in view, but in action have only one

Comment: Please, try my example. I think there is no point in debating your previous try.

Comment: work, thnks ) just needed moved `'multiple' => true` from attr to a higher level

Comment: @shuba.ivan Glad to hear that!